# PhpStorm: Remote host start directory

Tags: phpstorm

I have recently switched from PsPad to PhpStorm.

I edit a lot of files directly on various remote servers. I have successfully connected to my remote ftps and set up the workflow to edit files and save them to the remote server. 90% of my work is in a directory deep inside the remote host but sometimes I also have to edit other files a couple folders up. I would like to be standard in my 90% folder but be able to occasionally go up in the tree.

In PsPad I was able to set a start directory on the ftp and from there I could also go up if needed. For PhpStorm this is not possible since the root folder is fixed and doesnt allow me to go up in the tree ... Any ideas on how to fix this? Is there maybe a hotkey to enter a path on the remote host so I can make a keyboard macro or something?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a local copy of a file and it matches relative path in remote, you can quickly focus that file in Remote Host view via `Navigate | Select In ... | Remote Host`

Comment: Keep in mind: this IDE is built around "local code first" idea, which expects you to have your code on your computer and whatever is on remote is just a copy of it (we ignore generated content: product images and stuff). Deployment functionality is made for actual deployment (copying local file to remote) and downloading sources from remote; it's not made for "working with remote only" (means, it's not optimized for that, e.g. no starting folder like most S/FTP/S clients have).

Comment: @LazyOne I get the local code first idea and it is moslty for the better. I would just like to use one editor for all needs and the start folder is the only thing missing to make this a (almost) as good a soultion as PsPad was... I guess I'll have to come up with some sort of autohotkey macro...